# Apollo GraphQL server: In resolvers, get variables from several levels higher

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js, apollo, react-apollo

Say in my resolvers I have the following:

```
Query: {
  author: (root, args) => API.getAuthor(args.authorId),
},
Author: {
  book: (author, args) => API.getBook(author.id, args.bookId),
},
Book: {
  // Here, I can't get the author ID
  chapter: (book, args) => API.getChapter(authorId???, book.id, args.chapterId),
}
```

My problem is pretty clear from the above example, how can I access variables from several levels higher?
I'd like to be able to make a request like the following:

```
author(authorId: 1) {
  id
  book(bookId: 31) {
    id
    chapter(chapterId: 3) {
      content
    }
  }
}
```

And my connector to get a specific chapter also need the author's ID.

Comment: You can't, and that's intented

Comment: Doesn't the book have a 'author_id' field?

Comment: @whitep4nther Oh damn that sucks, why? And no, in my real-life case, book doesn't have a author_id field.

Comment: That is because the Book entity can also be included in others objects. You have right now `author { book { chapter } }`, but you can also have `library { book { chapter } }`. Each object is responsible for fetching his fields with his own data, which makes the whole thing composable. I'm having an idea for a solution though, so I'm writing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access variables from levels higher in GraphQL.

This is intended : because the `Book` entity can also be included in others objects. Right now, you have `author { book { chapter } }`, but you could also have `library { book { chapter } }`, where the `author` field would not present in the query, thus making the `author.id` variable inaccessible.

Each object is responsible for fetching his fields with his own data, which makes the whole thing composable.

What you could do, though, is extending the response of the `API.getBooks` function, to add the `author_id` field to the returned object. This way, you will be able to access it inside your `Book` entity : `book.authorId`.

```
function myGetBook(authorId, bookId) {
  return API.getBook(authorId, bookId)
    .then(book => {
      return Object.assign(
        {},
        theBook,
        { authorId }
      );
    });
}
```

And then:

```
Author: {
  book: (author, args) => myGetBook(author.id, args.bookId),
},
Book: {
  chapter: (book, args) => API.getChapter(book.authorId, book.id, args.chapterId),
}
```